# How do i keep my text still when minimize browser tab?

Tags: html, css

I tried creating a container with text. However my text kept getting squeeze when i minimize my browser tab. How do i make the text remain the same even when minimized?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Savana - About</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
    }
    .container-a {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      background-color: #ffd800;
    }
    .container-a h1 {
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      top: 100px;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div class="container-a">
      <h1>
            impeccable craftsmanship<br />
            ridiculously comfy shoes<br /> transformative impact
        </h1>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean to maintain the same words in the same lines when you resize the screen?

Comment: it's working perfectly for all sizes, what do you want?

Comment: Yeah thats right @Error404

Comment: I want it to remain still in its position even when the browser tab is resized @Bharat

Comment: @J.Koh, ok, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container is re-sizing as you adjust the window. You can help prevent this a few ways, for example like adding a min-width to your container so when it hits a certain size it will no longer get smaller.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Savana - About</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
    }
    .container-a {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      background-color: #ffd800;
      /* Added min width for your container here */
      min-width: 950px;
    }
    .container-a h1 {
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      top: 100px;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div class="container-a">
      <h1>
            impeccable craftsmanship<br />
            ridiculously comfy shoes<br /> transformative impact
        </h1>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah i put in on my body selector so that i dont have have to key in min-width on each container.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like these, it's proper way.

```
<div class="container-a" style=" resize: none;">
    <h1>
        impeccable craftsmanship<br />
        ridiculously comfy shoes<br /> transformative impact
    </h1>
</div>
```